# XCode IOS Paste To WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I maybe thinking in the wrong direction, so if there is a better way please make a suggestion.

I have a button on the top of my app that will run some methods of barcode reading.  I grab the string from the barcode and return to the webview.  If there is a textbox that I focused on I want to automatically paste the string.  So I have the string on the pasteboard, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to programmatically paste the string.  Is there anyway to call the paste method just as you do when you select the paste button on a text field?

Now I can see where I can inject javascript into the webview, but the textfields could be have multiple and random ID's.

Thanks.